# How to connect pop up to a button?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, popup

How to connect a pup up to a button ?

I want when i click a button pup up window to appear.
I have already made the pop up with some elements child-ed in the grid in the pop up.

I've tried this but it doesn't  work

```
private void Task_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (PopUp.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
       PopUp.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

I think maybe other parameter has to be changed for the pup up to appear.
Thanks for the help :D

Comment: have you tried setting the `Popup.IsOpen` to `true`?

Comment: Yeah I tried and it worked ass it should :D tnx

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you are doing Windows Form programing and the popup you are talking about must be a [Custom dialog box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (Simpler Version's [Tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/customized-dialog)). Assuming you have set the properties of your PopUp suitable for a dialog box,  you can use following :

```
using (PopUp pp = new PopUp())
{
    DialogResult result = pp.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: [link](http://s10.postimg.org/brutpbj21/Capture.png)
this is my pop up and i need it to appear when i click on a button the click function for me needs just to bring up the pop up window